# Varioref and previous page

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, varioref

With the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\declaretheorem[name=Lemma,Refname={Lemma,Lemmas}]{lem}

\begin{document}

\begin{lem}\label{lem1}
    A lemma.
\end{lem}

\clearpage

\begin{lem}\label{lem2}
    A lemma.
\end{lem}

\begin{lem}\label{lem3}
    A lemma.
\end{lem}

\Vref{lem1}, \Vref{lem2} and \Vref{lem3}.

\end{document}
```

Varioref produces: Lemma 1 on page 1, Lemma 2 and Lemma 3. Where I was
expecting: Lemma 1 on the previous page, Lemma 2 and Lemma 3.

Is it just me that don't understand varioref, or is there some option to get
the second behaviour ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You understand `varioref` correctly, but `cleveref` overwrites some of its functions and does so incorrectly. It is a typical case of adding `%` characters to the end of every line and in some cases that is simply **wrong**.

The `cleveref` packages makes a modified copy of the command `\@@vpageref` that contained the lines

```
    \advance\@tempcnta-2
    \ifnum \thevpagerefnum =\@tempcnta
```

The redefinition turns this into

```
    \advance\@tempcnta-2%                 <--- wrong %
    \ifnum \thevpagerefnum =\@tempcnta%
```

As a result TeX expands the `\ifnum` while still looking for the finish of the number `-2...` instead of substracting 2 from `\@tempcnta` and then doing the test.

In other words: blindly adding `%` the the end of every line in a definition can be harmful (the one on the next line is also useless but does no harm).

So the best fix is to get `cleveref` corrected. Short term solution: you can repatch it like this:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\cref@old@@vpageref
{\advance\@tempcnta-2}
{\advance\@tempcnta-2 }{\typeout{patch ok}}{\ERRORpatchFaild}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Nice example for my paper!

Comment: @egreg yes ... would have referenced it (but that question came too early)

Comment: I'll add it (with acknowledgment, of course). I'll also check if it's connected with my bug report about the missing `%` in `cleveref.sty` I showed in my talk.

Answer (score 4):

Ugh. I think some time ago I got fed up with tracking down spurious spacing errors in `cleveref`, and ran the source through sed to add % at the ends of all lines. That was dumb. But then, so is TeX's whitespace handling.

@Frank Mittelbach: Thanks for taking the time to track this down. This should be fixed in version 0.19.3 now on my [web site](http://www.dr-qubit.org/latex.php). The MWE from this question works, at least. I'll upload to CTAN after a bit more testing. (I added a `\relax` instead of removing the `%`, as it makes it slightly easier to track down spurious spaces if any more crop up in future.)

I fear there may be other similar bugs still lurking in `cleveref`, though.

Comment: Hi Toby, could this be updated in CTAN? The one on your website seems to work great, but it would be nice if it didn't need to be manually installed. I guess it's a weird one since although this is a 'correction', it wouldn't be entirely backwards compatible. Still, `cleveref` is great anyway :)