# \vref and \vpageref (from varioref) at page boundary are reported except if cleveref is used

Tags: cleveref, varioref

The following MWE (borrowed from [varioref: \vref or \vpageref at page boundary (may loop)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/104261/18401)) shows that `\vref` and `\vpageref` (from `varioref`) at page boundary are reported by errors (or warnings if `\vrefwarning` is placed in the preamble):

> Package varioref Error: \vref or \vpageref at page boundary [...] (may loop).

But, if `cleveref` is loaded, there is no report even in case of loops (as that happens with the MWE if the line `% \usepackage{cleveref}` is commented out).

Do you see how to get the report even if `cleveref` is used?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext,varioref}
% \usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{cleveref}{%
  \newcommand{\crossref}{\vref{tab:example}}
}{%
  \newcommand{\crossref}{table \vref{tab:example}}
}%
\makeatother

\newcommand{\test}{%
  \blindtext[3]

  These words are only for demonstration purposes. These words are only for
  demonstration purposes. These words are only for demonstration purposes. These
  words are only for demonstration purposes. These words are only for
  demonstration purposes. These words are only for demonstration purposes. These
  words are only for demonstration purposes. These words are only for
  demonstration purposes. These words are only for ... See \crossref

  \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l}
      Test\\
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Example Table}
    \label{tab:example}
  \end{table}
  \blindtext
}

\begin{document}
\test
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks like there's a bug in `cleveref`'s modification of `\vref`. You may want to contact the author of `cleveref` (email address at bottom of first page of the package's user guide) and draw his attention to this issue.

Comment: @Mico Author's attention drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might have been related to
[this bug](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257100/varioref-and-previous-page), which should now be fixed in the latest version (0.19.3) available from [my web site](http://www.dr-qubit.org/latex.php). At least, your MWE with `cleveref` enabled now produces the page-boundary warning.

Comment: Indeed, thanks! Regarding warning versus error, why not letting `cleveref` follow the `varioref`'s behavior (error by default and warnings if, and only if, `\vrefwarning` is placed in the preamble)?